# CloudFormation- Api Gateway Method change method request OAuth scopes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

using Cloudformation I am writing an API gateway method and I am trying to add OAuthScopes in the Method request section but I have no idea which code results in doing this. Currently, I have it as NONE.
Please note that I have my authorizer connected to user pool client and my user pool app client has the required oauth scopes. I just couldn't get them back on the API gateway method

[image]

[image]